# Haskell inheritance: What's inherity about it?

Tags: haskell, inheritance

Here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types in section Class inheritance, I read "A class can inherit from several other classes: just put all the ancestor classes in the parentheses before the =>."

I am puzzled when "(...)=>" is described as "inheritance".  So far as I can see, it's simply a class constraint. It merely says that this newly defined class (in the example: Real) applies to types which are already members (have instances for) the listed classes (Num and Ord).

In short, the "(...)=>" seems to me to act like a filter for qualities required of the types for which instances of this class may be created, and does not act to augment either the class or its instances.

Am I missing something? Is there some sense in which the "(...)=>" actually passes something along from "parent" to "child"?

Comment: If I write `interface A extends B { ... }` in Java, I'm giving the _constraint_ that any `A` must also be a `B`. This is the same as saying that `A` inherits all the capabilities of `B`.

Comment: @pelotom: Thanks for your comment. In Java terminology, there's a clear distinction between "interface inheritance" and "implementation inheritance". In your answer, I think you pointing out that (...)=> corresponds to _interface_ inheritance (ie: an inheritance of requirements). But then I'd have to argue against this being described as "A inherits the _capabilities_ of B", as that strikes me as implementation inheritance, which Java 'extends' does not do, and which I'm pretty sure Haskell => does not do either, though I can't think how to test this.

Comment: Actually both kinds can be found in Haskell! "Interface inheritance" corresponds to putting constraints in front of a class declaration. For example, `class Eq a => Ord a where ...` is saying that if a type is orderable, it also must have an equality relation--it's a requirement imposed on any would-be `Ord` instance. "Implementation inheritance" corresponds to putting constraints in front of an _instance_ declaration. For example, `instance Monad m => Applicative (WrappedMonad m)` is using the _capabilities_ of `Monad` to implement the _requirements_ of `Applicative`.

Comment: You'll find that Haskell uses the word class for a scenario where OO uses the word interface, so it's natural that the word inheritance when applied to Haskell classes would correspond to the OO concept of interface inheritance.

Comment: "inherity" made me smile, by the way. What a great adjectification.

Comment: @AndrewC "class ~= interface". Yes, and of course I knew that, just hadn't generalized it to this situation... no doubt continued distraction from the other meaning of 'class' in languages I use most of the time. Doh!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In practice, this means that all members of the subclass necessarily provide all methods of the superclass.

So, as in the linked example, we can write a method that requires `Eq`, but only give it an `Ord` constraint, and the `Eq` methods are implied for us.

(Note that inheritance is probably a terrible term for this, because it carries a lot of associations that don't make sense in our context. Nonetheless, I figured I might as well explain it.)

Comment: Between this answer and @pelotom, I think I'm pretty satisfied: "inheritance" here refers to this new class inheriting the _requirements_ of membership (via an instance) in the mentioned class(es). So indeed like interface inheritance in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Later reply, @gwideman, I think your original understanding was correct.

**In short, the "(...)=>" seems to me to act like a filter for qualities required of the types for which instances of this class may be created, and does not act to augment either the class or its instances**

That wiki page's "Class inheritance" is wrong. here is my reason.
in the page, it says.

**Here, it means that for a type to be an instance of Ord it must also be an instance of Eq, and hence needs to implement the == and /= operations**

if you run ghci, and type **:info Ord**,it shows following information:

```
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  max :: a -> a -> a
  min :: a -> a -> a
  {-# MINIMAL compare | (<=) #-}
```

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html, for explanation of "MINIMAL"

look at "**MINIMAL**" , it says, an instance of Ord only needs to implement compare **or** (<=) , which means, you do not needs to "implement the == and /= operations".
only that polymorphic 'a' needs to implement the == Or /= (check Eq's  MINIMAL pragmas)

(...)=> is type class constraint, not Java like interface inheritance.